# Cache headers set but network request still being sent

Tags: http, go, http-caching

I'm writing a golang server that serves images. When a request comes in I return the image and also set the HTTP Cache headers.

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.String() == "/sw.js" || r.URL.String() == "/favicon.ico" {
        return
    }

    // logic to get image

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.FormatInt(*result.ContentLength, 10))
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=2592000")
    io.Copy(w, result.Body)
})
```

Right now I'm just testing this out on my browser. I request an image and all of the headers are returned from the server correctly. I checked `chrome://cache/` and the url is there with all the correct headers set.

However when click `enter` again in the url address bar to re-request the image. The browser is still sending a network request to the server. Am I missing something from my response headers? I've also implemented this with etag header and just returning a `http.StatusNotModified` response if the etag key hasn't changed. However I'm trying to avoid the network request all together.

Comment: Add etag header.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Adding the etag header still sends the network request. Yes its more efficient because I can check the key but I'm trying to avoid the network request in the first place.

Comment: `Cache-Control` alone isn't enough. There are many headers that impact caching, including `Etag`, `Expires`, `Last-Modified`, `Pragma`, and others. And even still, browsers can make a request if they so choose, regardless of cache settings; and may send further cache-related headers such as `If-None-Match` or `If-Modified-Since`, to which you should correctly respond with `304 Not Modified` when appropriate. HTTP caching is not as simple as a single `Cache-Control` header.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) has an excellent run-down of HTTP caching that is a very helpful reference when implementing a service that intends to properly support caching.

Comment: Browsers will generally bypass their caches for manual reloads (they will at least send conditional requests). Also, caching may be disabled while the developer tools are open.